# SQL Server FOR XML Enclosing Element?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, for-xml

Using SQL Server 2008, I have a query that emits a result set using FOR XML. Right now it is a non-compliant fragment.

How can I wrap my result XML in an enclosing element and then put a simple XML declaration on top with a single schema/namespace reference to make the output compliant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have the XML processing instruction in a XML datatype in SQL Server.

See [Limitations of the XML Data Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

This code

```
declare @XML xml =  
  '<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>Value</root>'

select @XML
```

Has the output

```
<root>Value</root>
```

You can build the XML as a string with the XML processing instruction in place.

```
declare @XML xml = '<root>Value</root>'
declare @XMLStr nvarchar(max) = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'
  
set @XMLStr = @XMLStr + cast(@XML as nvarchar(max))

select @XMLStr
```

Output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?><root>Value</root>
```

Comment: The C# coder in me says that I am "wasting" memory by doubling string usage, but if that's the best way (and MSSQL handles the string garbase collection), I guess there's no problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add "WITH XMLNAMESPACES" to the beginning and a ROOT() to the FOR XML clause:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://namespace_uri_here' )
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('TopLevel')
```