# SQL Server table data to xml file with column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have this kind of data:

[image: Data]

Is it possible to produce this XML file as output with a SQL query from that table?

[image: XML]

Comment: I know SQL can give you XML like `<data_t><code>subxxx</code><amount>123.00</amount><data_t/>`.. but not like the result you expecting

Comment: Yep. I manage also produce XML file with root and tags - bur receiving side needs file in this format. :/

Comment: I personally don't think you can get this with SQL, it seems more than normal XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what issues you actually had but you need to use `for xml path()` and nest them in a couple of sub-queries.

```
declare @T table(code varchar(30), amount money);

insert into @T(code, amount) values
('totalPAS', 389),
('sub270', 0),
('sub770', 0),
('sub270', 0);

select 'datfile' as '@objectCode', 
       (
       select T.code as '@instanceCode',
              'data_t' as '@objectCode',
              (
              select 'code' as 'ColumnValue/@name',
                     T.code as 'ColumnValue',
                     null,
                     'amount' as 'ColumnValue/@name',
                     T.amount as 'ColumnValue'
             for xml path('CustomInformation'), type
             ) 
       from @T as T
       for xml path('instance'), type
       )
for xml path('customObjectInstances');
```

Result:

Comment: Wow! Worked! Thousand times thank You!
One option:
If I have so called header information for the file - what would be the easiest way to add that into the result?

Comment: @Tsy79 if you are talking about the XML declaration have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423560/sql-server-for-xml-enclosing-element

Comment: Please find my next level question below.